# How to change the value of "type" field in ColorMatrix filter in fabric js?

Tags: fabricjs

I am using ColorMatrix filter in fabric js and I want to change the value of type field in this. I tried the below approach but it's not working and default value is "ColorMatrix":

```js
new window.fabric.Image.filters.ColorMatrix({
    type: 'SomeFilterName',
    matrix: [
        1.3, -0.3, 1.1, 0, 0,
        0, 1.3, 0.2, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0.8, 0.2, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    ]
});
```

Comment: Use something else except `type` as it is used while we are loading from json to find the respective classes

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to change existing filter type. You have to instantiate another filter type with an old `matrix`:

```
let filter = new fabric.Image.filters.ColorMatrix({
    matrix: [
        1.3, -0.3, 1.1, 0, 0,
        0, 1.3, 0.2, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0.8, 0.2, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
    ]
});

let matrix = filter.matrix;

filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Convolute({
    matrix: matrix
});
```